# Creating an HTML page from python

Tags: python, html

My python code generates a list and a dictionary of strings.

I want to create an HTML page and insert these values inside a table.

I had a look at template engines like yaptu, but I need something simpler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<html><body><table>'

for item in my_list:
    html += '<tr>{0}</tr>'.format(str(item)) # this sort of thing

for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    html += '<tr>{0}</tr>'.format(v) # or whatever

html += '</table></body></html>' # now you have the full html string

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

html = soup.prettify() # this would actually auto close unclosed tags for you too

>>> print html

<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <rows>
         </rows> # etc.
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

info on [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and it's [**docs**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

**EDIT:**

With regards to your comment

```
import os

os.chdir(path) # will change your cwd to path if you have a specific one in mind
```

To save the newly generated html file to the cwd:

```
with open('new.html', 'w') as f: # with will auto create file and close after writing
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: Will this create an HTML file in my cwd?

Comment: Well, you didn't mention this in your question, so no it wouldn't, but please see my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot! This pretty much did the work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use built-in Python formatting features, but you had to provide own code for repetition and stuff like that. Instead you may use some simple template mechanism like [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) (Python version is named [pystache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pystache)).